# x86 jmp to register

Tags: assembly, x86

So I have a address in `%eax` I would like to jmp to but the code will not compile, is there a way around this?

```
movl 0xdeadbeef, %eax

jmp %eax ; <--- compile error: type mismatch for 'jmp'
```

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: @Crashworks, only GAS (counting mainstream assemblers only) uses this weird and unreadable syntax...

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since nobody was able to provide you with the correct answer, here it is:

```
jmp   *%eax
```

Comment: I wonder why the only correct answer at the time being got voted down ^^ Care to explain, beloved downvoter?

Answer (score 6):

```
// target address in eax
jmp   *%eax

// target pointer address in eax
jmp   *(%eax)
```

For x86_64, the register is: `%rax`

Answer (score 5):

if nothing else works, you can always use the following trick:

```
push eax
ret
```

Comment: more like `pushl %eax # ret` in the case of AT&T syntax :)

Comment: thanks @NiklasB.! I was just giving the idea... I'm not familiar with AT&T syntax, but I didn't want the idea to pass...

Comment: Note that most modern 80x86 CPUs keep track of calls/returns in a buffer so that they can predict what address RET will return to (and continue with speculative execution) before they know what RET will actually return to. Faked returns will kill that and hurt performance, starting with an immediate "return mispredicted" (rather than a possible "jmp/branch predicted") and possibly continuing with subsequent "return mispredictions" for the depth of the return buffer. Basically, don't do it unless you have to (and you don't have to in this case).

Comment: Good point @Brendan. But don't a JMP to register create similar penalty since the register content is unknown until the actual jump occurs? I tried to find a reference talking about penalties but I failed. Can you point me to one? Thanks!

Comment: For the first time executed, a calculated jump will not be predicted. But if it is executed more than once, the branch prediction might detect repeating target addresses (think of a default case in a `switch` statement) or repeating patterns (if there are any) of addresses. Of course, randomly taken branches will almost never be predicted correctly. Google for Agner Fog microarchitecture